# Get different errors while adding file to repository

Tags: github

I am working on a project with my team and i have access to repository with different branches. I have to add new files to "Backend" branch. But i faced with different erros.

```
C:\Users\MARSHAL\Desktop\git_project work>git remote add origin https://github.com/ranebof/EasyO.git
C:\Users\MARSHAL\Desktop\git_project work>git checkout -b Backend
C:\Users\MARSHAL\Desktop\git_project work>git add .
C:\Users\MARSHAL\Desktop\git_project work>git commit -m "addedBot"
  On branch Backend
  Your branch and 'origin/Backend' have diverged,
  and have 1 and 48 different commits each, respectively.
    (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

  nothing to commit, working tree clean


C:\Users\MARSHAL\Desktop\git_project work>git push
  To https://github.com/ranebof/EasyO
   ! [rejected]        Backend -> Backend (non-fast-forward)
  error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/ranebof/EasyO'
  hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
  hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
  hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
  hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

C:\Users\MARSHAL\Desktop\git_project work>git pull
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

Comment: Rebase your changes on top of the branch you are trying to push to.

Comment: But how to do this